# Firefox search result in the middle

Tags: firefox, plugins

This has been annoying me for a while. When I search (ctrl+F or just start typing for quick find) for something, and Firefox finds something it puts the search result **completely at the top of the page**.

Now, not only is this annoying, some pages use a floating header that gets over the found occurence and hides it. This forces me to scroll to see every occurence.

Does a plugin exist that puts the search result in the middle of the screen instead of completely at the top?

Comment: Good question, I've wondered about this for a while (especially when Firefox is "finding" something and it's actually out of the current viewing frame!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't happen on 5.0 it displays it at the bottom of the page

[image]

EDIT -

This extension displays the searched word in the middle of the page -

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/find-to-center/

Comment: That's better, for sure, but would it be possible to get it in the middle instead? I need context to see if this occurrence was what I were looking for.

Comment: Please see edit in my answer